# Why can DFS handle a graph with multiple components while BFS cannot?

Tags: graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, connected-components

Consider the standard pseudocode for BFS (modified from CLRS)

```
def BFS(G, source):
  Initialize Boolean array visited to keep track of visited nodes
  Mark source as visited
  Add source to queue Q

  while Q is not empty:
    u = Q.dequeue()
    for v in G[u]:
      if v is not visited:
        mark v as visited and add to queue
```

This version of BFS runs on a starting vertex `source` and will visit all vertices reachable from `source`. Yet if `G` has multiple components, `BFS()` won't visit all the vertices in `G`. It therefore makes sense to me to have the function

```
def BFS_wrapper(G):
for source in G:
  if source not in visited:
    BFS(source)
```

which will enable BFS to reach all the vertices in the entire graph `G`, even if `G` has multiple components. Yet the standard pseudocode for BFS does not include this wrapper. Moreover, the standard pseudocode for DFS seems to always has this exact 'wrapper' function that let's DFS reach all the vertices in the entire graph `G`, even if `G` has multiple components.

My question is: why does the standard DFS code have this wrapper function while the standard BFS code does not? It seems like DFS is meant to be used on a graph with multiple components while BFS is only meant to be used on a graph with a single component. Equivalently, why does BFS seem like it is not meant to run on a graph with multiple components but DFS is?

Comment: what makes you think DFS can jump components? it can't. -- if you seed your algorithm with a node from each component, that's cheating. you could just as well formulate BFS with multiple initial nodes. -- I think your confusion stems from what algorithms you're really looking at. what you describe as "standard DFS" isn't plain DFS, it's something else.

Comment: you should ask this on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ because it's about algorithms and discrete math, not about programming. programming is just implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing the queue `q` with a vertex from each component allows BFS to simultaneously explore the different components. Thus, we don't need a 'wrapper' function to give `BFS` the ability to explore a graph with multiple components.